# Passing Date to javascript function

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //calling procedure which displays list of items by default.
    DisplayList(2, '2', '2', 0);
});

DisplayList(2, fromDate, toDate, selectedvalue) {
//parameter 2 is passed for procedure
}

function Functioncalling {
    // fromDate and toDate values from asp textbox
    DisplayList(2, fromDate, toDate, selectedvalue);
}
```

fromdate and todates has 'year' value. loss of day and month values as well as different year which is not selected. when DisplayList from function is called.

Please help me out to get .
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

if `DisplayList(2, fromDate, toDate, selectedvalue) {...}` is kind of declaration you can not use a number as a parameter name `2`;

Comment: I want to pass fromdate and todate to DisplayList function. Eg : if i pass 2014-08-01 and 2015-01-01 then i will get fromdate as 2001 and todate as 2013. But i need 2014-08-01 and 2015-01-01 for fromdate and todate. parameter 2 is not a problem. i pass 2 to procedure not to function.